# Render p:outputPanel after every AJAX Call

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a p:outputPanel which I want to render if I have a Java Object with data. If the object is null I don't want to render the panel.

```
<h:form id="treeform">
    <p:outputPanel id="outputComponent" rendered="#{TreeViewController.compProfile}">
        <div>
            .........
        </div>
    </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>

public boolean getCompProfile()
{

    if (cd == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I noticed that the code is working properly. If the object is null the boolean value is false and the panel is not displayed. But the problem that I found is that when I make again AJAX call the boolean value is always false no matter if the Java object is null or not. Can I somehow configure the p:outputPanel after AJAX call to check the `#{TreeViewController.compProfile}` property to render or not the panel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change

```
<p:outputPanel id="outputComponent" rendered="#{TreeViewController.compProfile}">
```

Into

```
<p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">
    <p:outputPanel  id="outputComponent" rendered="#{TreeViewController.compProfile}">
</p:outputPanel>
```

Or don't add the wrapper and add the `treeform` id to your `update` attribue of your ajax (`p:ajax` or `p:commandButton`)

Like this `update="treeform"`

Comment: If the component isn't rendered in first place, then it can't be auto updated. Plus, with `autoUpdate="true"` it isn't necessary to specify its client ID in `update`.

Comment: That's better. I only wonder which sheeps have upvoted the wrong answer twice before.